# Flutter Themedata Refrector

Tags: flutter, dart, coding-style

How can write readable and clean code flutter `ThemeData` for light mode and dark mode.
I already wrote but that is not readable how should i write for themedata for lightmode and darkmode readable, maintain and clearly?

Comment: what did you done , please include here?

Comment: i mean, i just created darkmode method and light mode method but i just another added or maintain it is not readable. so how should i write for dark mode and light mode readable

Answer (score 0):

You can easily store your theme preference in form of a string and then at the start of your app check if there is value stored on file system, if so apply that theme as shown below.

**StorageManager.dart**

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class StorageManager {
  static void saveData(String key, dynamic value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (value is int) {
      prefs.setInt(key, value);
    } else if (value is String) {
      prefs.setString(key, value);
    } else if (value is bool) {
      prefs.setBool(key, value);
    } else {
      print("Invalid Type");
    }
  }

  static Future<dynamic> readData(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    dynamic obj = prefs.get(key);
    return obj;
  }

  static Future<bool> deleteData(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.remove(key);
  }
}
```

Define your theme properties in a theme variable like below and initialize your _themedata variable on the basis of value inside storage.

**ThemeManager.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../services/storage_manager.dart';

class ThemeNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  final darkTheme = ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
    primaryColor: Colors.black,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF212121),
    accentColor: Colors.white,
    accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
    dividerColor: Colors.black12,
  );

  final lightTheme = ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
    primaryColor: Colors.white,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE5E5E5),
    accentColor: Colors.black,
    accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
    dividerColor: Colors.white54,
  );

  ThemeData _themeData;
  ThemeData getTheme() => _themeData;

  ThemeNotifier() {
    StorageManager.readData('themeMode').then((value) {
      print('value read from storage: ' + value.toString());
      var themeMode = value ?? 'light';
      if (themeMode == 'light') {
        _themeData = lightTheme;
      } else {
        print('setting dark theme');
        _themeData = darkTheme;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  void setDarkMode() async {
    _themeData = darkTheme;
    StorageManager.saveData('themeMode', 'dark');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setLightMode() async {
    _themeData = lightTheme;
    StorageManager.saveData('themeMode', 'light');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Wrap your app with themeProvider and then apply theme using consumer. By doing so whenever you change the value of theme and call notify listeners widgets rebuild to sync changes.

**Main.dart**

```
void main() {
  return runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier>(
    create: (_) => new ThemeNotifier(),
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(
      builder: (context, theme, _) => MaterialApp(
        theme: theme.getTheme(),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Hybrid Theme'),
          ),
          body: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => {
                    print('Set Light Theme'),
                    theme.setLightMode(),
                  },
                  child: Text('Set Light Theme'),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => {
                    print('Set Dark theme'),
                    theme.setDarkMode(),
                  },
                  child: Text('Set Dark theme'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/mateenkiani/theming_flutter) is the link to github repository.